# Issues in Selected property of MenuItem of Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The "selected" property of `MenuItem` it isn't working in `Select`.
Please check https://codesandbox.io/s/9j8z661lny

I tried to compare using `Id`, also you can only write `selected={true}` and it did not mark the words that are already selected

Probably I'm using the component in a wrong way, however I will accept any recommendation to obtain the behavior I desire.

Thanks in advance for your time.
Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything with the `selected` prop on `MenuItem` -- it gets set automatically. What you do need is for the `MenuItem` value to match a value in the `Select`'s value array.

Currently you are using objects as your values. Material-UI supports using objects, but the equality check will only work if you are using the **exact same objects** (`===` must be true) for your selected values and your `MenuItem` values.

In your case, you have two sets of objects -- one for your selected groups (passed as the `Select` value) and one for the full set of groups (used for the `MenuItem` values). Though the two sets of objects contain matching information, none of the objects from the full set will be equal (`===`) to any of the objects in the selected groups.

I recommend that you use just the "id"s for the values. Then to produce the `Chip`s for your selected values, you just need to be able to look up a group by its id.

Here's a working example based on your sandbox:

[image: Edit Issues in Selected property]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time to answer me, I understand your explanation. 
But I getting this error in my project TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined, when I tried to pass the group.id.

Like you may know, the total of groups and the selected groups Im receiving from an API. 

Im using async/await . 

Do you have any comment? Why it is appearing this error?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the structure of your real code.

Comment: I resolved the issue. I have passing in the reduce function wrong parameter, the id for me is uppercase and I have been using wrong.
Your help was Amazing!
Thanks a lot !